# Is 'next' a reserved Javascript identifier?

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

Is 'next' a reserved Javascript identifier?  The following code of mine was silently failing (in FF 3) to create the object's key/value pair when the key was 'next'.  However, when I switched my keys from prev/next to navPrev and navNext, the object gets constructed as I expected.

```
        var unimplementedNavEvent = function() {console.log('Un-implemented Page Navigation Event')};
        var navigationEventStubs = [];

        for (var i=0, n=pages.length; i<n; i++) {
            var pageNavEvents = {href: pages[i], navEvents: {}};
            if (i !== 0) {
                pageNavEvents.navEvents.prev = unimplementedNavEvent;
            }
            if (i < n-1) {
                pageNavEvents.navEvents.next = unimplementedNavEvent;
            }
            navigationEventStubs.push(pageNavEvents);
        }
```

Comment: Demonstrate on jsfiddle.net please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, check out this list of reserved JavaScript keywords:

http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

**Edit:**

Actually, there would appear to be some use of the word as a function in JavaScript 1.7 gerator/iterators

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7

Comment: +1.  Note that ECMAScript 5th edition has *future reserved words* that aren't listed on that site... but `next` isn't one of those either.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words would be a better link.

Comment: Horrible page, “Java Keywords (Reserved by JavaScript)” and “Other JavaScript Keywords” are merely horrible: they interchange Java and JavaScript and DOM methods and properties and JavaScript keywords. Furthermore, some ‘keywords’ like `Location` and `Textarea` can be used as property names. Next time, please refer to [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Prototype or another Javascript framework? `next` is part of Prototype's ultimate DOM traversal tookit:

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/next